# ASP.Net MVC 2.0 Client-Side Validation Posting Back

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, client-side

I have been trying this based on Scott Gu's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

My problem is that although my scripts are running (checked in firebug) and I don't get any errors.  My page is still going to the server.  I have javascript enabled too ;)

I have the following view code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Part1a.ViewModels.ProductModel>" %>
```

Create

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<h2>Create Product</h2>    

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>               
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>            
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Owner) %>        
        <%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Owner) %> 
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner)%>  

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

And have used Data Annotations:

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[DisplayName("Owner")]
[Required]
[StringLength(60)]
public string Owner { get; set; }
```

I'm also using Entity Framwork 4.0.

Does anyone have any idea why my page is still posting back?

Many Thanks

Ted

Comment: 2.0 sorry - ahead of the game :)

Answer (score 0):

This is consistent with behavior I've been getting in ASP.NET MVC since I started using it over a year ago.  I haven't actually tried the RTM of 2.0, but I'm hearing that it's the same there as well- the client side validation emitting just doesn't work.

This thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75e95329-50ff-472f-80c6-52bda0a329d9/aspnet-mvc-2-client-side-validation-not-working-for-htmlvalidationmessage?forum=aspmvc) addresses the issue, and suggests you get the scripts from MVC Futures, which I've also seen before.

This link might also help:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rickandy/client-side-validation-for-mvc-2-p2?wa=wsignin1.0)

That link above leads to an article that suggests you use the CDN versions of the scripts.  I haven't tried that yet- it might work better because you're guaranteed to get a current, supported script.